# Xsl failing in Sitecore install

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I have a Sitecore 6.2.0 (rev. 091012) installed and working perfectly, except one thing - every xsl rendering i have is failing to run, and the xsl error i get is "System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Demo.Samples.XslHelper, MyDemo.....". I have no idead what this is and how to fix this - any suggestions?
My user controls are working without a glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching your web.config for "Demo.Samples.XslHelper", then you will properly find a xslExtension that Sitecore cant find, remove it.

Comment: I already tried searching the web.config bu without any luck - then i realised that there also was the App_Config/Include folder, and this contained a XslExtension.config that contained a Demo.Samples.XslHelper - removing this solved the problem. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably declaring a namespace in the top, which in turn is registered to a demo DLL that you don't have.

Paste the XSL file here, if none of this makes any sense to you, and the source of the error should be straight forward to identify.

Comment: Besides my own usual xsl files, i have also tried with a "blank" xsl file to see if that worked - but same error occured. Here is the code of sitecore's default xsl file when you create a new one - this one is also failing with the excat same error;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--=============================================================
    File: xsltest.xslt                                                   
    Created by: sitecore\admin

Comment: Created: 29-11-2009 16:27:56                                               
    Copyright notice at bottom of file
==============================================================-->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:sc="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" 
  xmlns:dot="http://www.sitecore.net/dot"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dot sc">

Comment: That did not work very well.. here is a link to a file; http://drop.io/cjockey/asset/xsl-error-xslt